# Applying 'Loadmask' to FullCalendar has strange results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I'm using [FullCalendar 1.5.1](http://blog.arshaw.com/1/post/2011/04/fullcalendar-151-released.html), and I'm getting strange results when I pair it with '[jQuery Loadmask](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/)' across different browsers.

The loadmask appears normally in Firefox, and I've also tried the adaptation in Chrome.

If I pause the script in the debugger *immediately* before and after the calendar begins to fire the asynchronous background events to display various elements, I see the mask. Running in regular time however, I don't see the loadmask at all in Internet Explorer, Chrome, etc.

I see it just fine in **Firefox**!?

1. So far I've thought it was a z-index, overlay issue with jQuery UI, but this has proved not to have much of an affect using the Loadmask adapted to use jQuery UI -
2. I've also tried to add artificial delay using the time-out function, etc. and it still does not display over the calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out:

You can wrap part of the **$.ajax** function internal to the calendar with some delay:

```
setTimeout(function() {
                    $.ajax($.extend({}, ajaxDefaults, source, {
                            data: data,
                            success: function(events) {
                                events = events || [];
                                var res = applyAll(success, this, arguments);
                                if ($.isArray(res)) {
                                    events = res;
                                }
                                callback(events);
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                applyAll(error, this, arguments);
                                callback();
                            },
                            complete: function() {
                                applyAll(complete, this, arguments);
                                popLoading();
                            }
                    }))
                }, options.fetchDelay);
```